# How do I get an XML attribute with XmlReader.Create?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml, rss

I am using XmlReader.Create to retrieve data from an RSS xml file. Then I am putting this data into a DataSet and binding it to a ListView:

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(this.RssUrl);
XmlDataDocument xdoc = new XmlDataDocument();
xdoc.DataSet.ReadXml(xmlReader, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
```

The problem is that one of the fields I am trying to get is in an attribute. How do I get the "url" attribute from "media:thumbnail" below?

```
<item> 
  <title>Some Title</title> 
  <description>Content goes here...</description> 
  <link>http://www.mydomain.com?id=439</link> 
  <guid>453252362</guid> 
  <pubDate>Sat, 21 Aug 2010 11:00:00 GMT</pubDate> 
  <media:thumbnail url="http://www.mydomain.com/catalog/1111tn.jpg" /> 
  <media:content url="http://www.mydomain.com/catalog/1111.jpg" /> 
</item>
```

I am bind it like this, but the media:thumbnail is null obviously because I need to get the attribute some how:

```
void singleItem_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label singleItem = (Label)sender;
    singleItem.Text = String.Format(@"                    
        <div class=""rlvI content"">
            <div class=""image"">
                <a href=""{0}""><img src=""{1}"" alt=""{2}""></a>
            </div>
            <p>
                <span class=""title"">{2}</span><br />
                {3}
            </p>
        </div>",
        ((singleItem.NamingContainer as RadListViewDataItem).DataItem as DataRowView)["link"],
        ((singleItem.NamingContainer as RadListViewDataItem).DataItem as DataRowView)["media:thumbnail"],
        ((singleItem.NamingContainer as RadListViewDataItem).DataItem as DataRowView)["title"],
        ((singleItem.NamingContainer as RadListViewDataItem).DataItem as DataRowView)["description"]);
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. In any case, for any Xml work in C# my advice is to switch to the new Linq `XElement` api's. They are sooooo much easier that the rest.

Comment: +1 for jdv's advice. `XmlReader` is useful when you need to read *huge* amounts of XML, but an RSS feed is very unlikely to be very large. LINQ to XML FTW.

Comment: +1 for jdv's comment. Go for LINQ to XML!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get the "url" attribute from "media:thumbnail" below?

You need to read through the document (`while (xmlReader.Read() {...}`) until you get to the element with the attribute on it. Then you can use methods like [`ReadAttributeValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readattributevalue.aspx).

In the read loop you can match on node type, node name and namespace to ensure you have the right element.